# what is exactly the ‘OSfile_return’ that the ARIES algorithm paper mentioned？ And why we need that for database？

Tags: database, algorithm, transactions, recovery, aries

what is exactly the ‘OSfile_return’ that the ARIES algorithm paper mentioned？ And why we need that for database？

The Paper said that:

> For each pending action which involves erasing or returning a file to the operating system, we write
> an OSfile. return redo-only log record.

But I doesn't understand what  exactly the ‘OSfile_return’ is, and what it for.

[image]